# Is there a biography about Verda Majo?

Tags: culture, history

I've been looking for a book of some kind about [Teru Hasegawa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teru_Hasegawa) and, so far, I've only found one PDF from the university of Heidelberg.

Comment: Could someone tell me what I can change/what the problem is with this question? I don't know what to improve if it's just voted down...

Comment: I don't know why you'd get a downvote. Hmm. I just came here to say I'm also really interested in information about Verda Majo but I don't have additional information about her.

Answer (score 5):

En la esperantlingva Vikipedio vi trovas artikolon pri Verda Majo:
https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verda_Majo#Libroj
Ĝi entenas sufiĉe longan biografieton pri ŝi.
Sub la rubriko "verkaro" vi trovas libron pri Hasegawa Teru:

Gotelind MÜLLER: Hasegawa Teru ali-nome Verda Majo (1912-1947). Japana esperantistino en la ĉina kontraŭjapana rezisto. Trad. Reinhard Haupenthal. Bad Bellingen: Edition Iltis 2010. 23p. ISBN 9783932807855

Tiu libro haveblas en la librovendejo de UEA:
http://katalogo.uea.org/index.php?inf=8470

Salutas vin
Alois Eder